# Is it possible to read Excel data from specific cells using PX.Data.XLSXReader?

Tags: c#, excel, acumatica, acumatica-kb

Is it possible to read Excel data from specific cells using PX.Data.XLSXReader?
I'm trying to read a specific column from an Excel file using Acumatica's XLSXReader library but I have been unable to find a function to get the information of a specific cell(s) - e.g. H7.
It would appear that I need to define an index for the columns in order to iterate and get the information. However, in my case the excel file does not include information in the first row, and we are unable to modify it because it's automatically generated by a third party.
This is my action:

```
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Upload Data", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select, Visible = true)]
    [PXButton()]
    public virtual IEnumerable uploadFileBatch(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
        string complete = "";
        if (this.NewFilePanel.AskExt() == WebDialogResult.OK)
        {
            PX.SM.FileInfo info = PXContext.SessionTyped<PXSessionStatePXData>().FileInfo[SessionKey] as PX.SM.FileInfo;
            byte[] bytes = info.BinData;
            List<string> pONotFound = new List<string>();
            using (PX.Data.XLSXReader reader = new XLSXReader(bytes))
            {
                reader.Reset();
                Dictionary<String, Int32> indexes = reader.IndexKeyPairs.ToDictionary(p => p.Value.ToUpper(), p => p.Key);
                while (reader.MoveNext())
                {
                    //This is correct when there is info in the first row with those titles
                    string data = reader.GetValue(indexes["TITLE"]).Trim() + "\n";
                    //However I would like to do something like this
                    string data2 = reader.GetValue("H7").Trim() + "\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Also, I have noticed that when I don't include

```
 Dictionary<String, Int32> indexes = reader.IndexKeyPairs.ToDictionary(p => p.Value.ToUpper(), p => p.Key);
```

the code doesn't iterate with

```
 reader.MoveNext()
```

I understand why Acumatica uses the first row to identify the columns and help with the mapping during the upload of documents - but I'm thinking of managing the library with more flexibility - if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to read Excel data from specific cells using PX.Data.XLSXReader?

Yes it is possible to get the specific cell of a row using `GetValue` method like in your example.

It is not possible to have random access to rows as they use an IEnumerator:

```
IEnumerator<Worksheet.Row> _rowIterator;
```

However first row is a special case that is accessed through the `IndexKeyPairs` property.

> Also, I have noticed that when I don't include […] the code doesn't
>   iterate with

Accessing the `IndexKeyPairs` property has the side-effect of assigning the `_keys` private member. It is possible that this side-effect changes the behavior of the `XLSXReader` class.

```
public IDictionary<int, string> IndexKeyPairs
{
    get
    {
        if (_keys == null)
        {
            _keys = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            if (_headerRow != null)
                foreach (Worksheet.Cell cell in _headerRow.Cells)
                    _keys.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(cell.Address.Column, GetValue(cell)));
        }
        return _keys;
    }
}
```

> I'm thinking of managing the library with more flexibility - if
>   possible.

The library was optimized for speed which requires sequential iterator instead of random access. It might not be as convenient but the `MoveNext` method is designed to be fast. To access a specific row, call the `Reset` method to reset the iterator and call `MoveNext` repeatedly until the target row is reached.

To assess available functionalities provided by `XLSXReader` class look up the `IContentReader` interface:

```
public interface IContentReader : IDisposable
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Move to next record in data source
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>true, if the operation was performed successfully</returns>
    bool MoveNext();

    /// <summary>
    /// Find value in record by given key index
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="index">index of value</param>
    /// <returns>null, if given key index was not found</returns>
    string GetValue(int index);

    /// <summary>
    /// Reset state of reader
    /// </summary>
    void Reset();

    /// <summary>
    /// Collection of value keys
    /// </summary>
    IDictionary<int, string> IndexKeyPairs { get; }
}
```

Comment: "To access a specific row, call the Reset method to reset the iterator and call MoveNext repeatedly until the target row is reached" can this be done without values in the first row to identify the column? I tested something along those lines and GetValue() returned null.

Comment: First row is a special case, you need to call MoveNext once to initialize the iterator. GetValue takes an integer parameter, if you call MoveNext once and then pass the column index (0,1,2,3,4...) I would not expect GetValue to return null.

Comment: If you try to resolve IndexKeyPairs["TITLE"] when you have no header then I would expect it to fail. That's likely your issue. I would expect GetValue("H7") to fail to compile based on my version of GetValue which takes Int parameter. GetValue(0) should get you first column cell of current row.

Comment: Also: 
1) Can we use this library for XLS files? instead of XLSX
2) Do you foresee any issues with the use of 3rd party libraries i.e. EPPlus

Comment: For both questions, you need to test it. I got neither of those on hand.